# How to get a text on a picture if the mouse is on it?

Tags: html, css, image, blur, effect

I want my picture to get blurry with text on it when my mouse is on the image, i got it blurry already now i want to get text on the image at the moment the picture is getting blurry. This is what i have now but now i dont have a idea to get text on it. I am kinda new to this so maybe its too advanced for now but maybe you guys can help me a bit with it.

css:

```
.blur img {
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.blur img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="blur">
  <img src="picture.png" alt="picture">
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Aliquam ac varius arcu, sed luctus neque. 
   Nam varius sem vel nisi condimentum congue. 
</div>
```

Comment: What text? Where? C'mon you can do better when asking questions!

Comment: here no class found like `.blur` post related code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul class="img-list">
<li>
<a href="http://nataliemac.com">
<img src="http://geekgirllife.com/images/filename.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
<span class="text-content"><span>Place Name</span></span>
</a>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.img-list {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
display: inline-block;
height: 150px;
margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
position: relative;
width: 150px;
} 

span.text-content span {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
} 
span.text-content {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
display: table;
height: 150px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 150px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms;
transition: opacity 500ms;
} 

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
opacity: 1;
}
```

[Reference](http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/93jx5pjf/)

I have used this css:

```
.blur img {
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.blur img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.blur:hover .inner{
    opacity:1;
}
.blur{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
.blur span{
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    font-size:24px;
    opacity:0;
}
```